# Any idea why this Paperjs script has a certain amount of lag

Tags: javascript, jquery, paperjs

I wrote this script, and when I move the slider, the squares should instantly resize. They dont. It takes a few seconds. Any ideas?

Here's a link to my code: [code on github gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/54d583288de778798024). [image: You should be able to drag the slider and the squares resize]. Why does it delay?

Answer (score 1):

You should add paper.view.draw() after you resize the squares so paper will update the canvas. It's redrawing internally but not updating the canvas.

There might be an issue with using on("change") as well - see this issue: [onchange event on input range not triggering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544890/onchange-event-on-input-type-range-is-not-triggering-in-firefox-while-dragging)