# javascript and class class=input-range doesn't work in ie

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, slider, range

I am having an issue with some simple javascript not working in ie. My code is here:

```
<script>
function test(){
var myDivElem = document.getElementById("mydiv");
var sizerange= document.getElementById("sizeID");
myDivElem.innerHTML = sizerange.value;
}
</script>

<div>
<p>

<form action="url-link-here" method="post">

<span id="mydiv">100</span>

<input class="input-range" id="sizeID" oninput="test()" type="range" name="size" value="100" min="5" max="250" step ="5">
```

It works just fine in all other browsers.

Comment: Try 'onchange' instead of 'oninput'. :)

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999998/javascript-innerhtml-is-not-working-for-ie Normal IE problem it would seem.

Comment: Thanks a million! Now it works as intended in IE however the value only change on mouse-release in other browsers. Hmm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **onchange** instead of **oninput**. Worked in IE11

```js
function test() {
    var myDivElem = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    var sizerange = document.getElementById("sizeID");
    myDivElem.innerHTML = sizerange.value;
  }
```

```html
<form action="url-link-here" method="post">

  <span id="mydiv">100</span>

  <input class="input-range" id="sizeID" oninput="test()" onchange="test()" type="range" name="size" value="100" min="5" max="250" step="5">
</form>
```

Comment: Now it works as intended in IE however the value only change on mouse-release in other browsers.

Comment: Ok, the solution is of cause to just call both onchange and oninput. Thanks!

Comment: <input class="input-range" id="sizeID" onchange="test()" oninput="test()" type="range" name="size" value="100" min="5" max="250" step ="5">

Comment: @PeterWang Oh I did not check for other browsers. Anyways I have edited the answer. Can you please mark it as correct. Thanks