# How to trigger on text change inside a <strong>?

Tags: jquery

How to trigger on text change inside a ?

I have input field using a draggable range slider, the value from the slider gets printed into this .

I want to trigger a function when the value changes inside the

```
<strong><span class="description"></span><i>verdi i kg:</i></strong>
<input type="text" style="border: 0px !important">
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: instead of listening for text change inside `strong` listen for value change on range slider.

Comment: There is no event to handle text change in `i` element. Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657686/jquery-event-detect-changes-to-the-html-text-of-a-div), may be useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the mousemove event:

```
    $(':input').mousemove(function(){
        $('span').html($(':input').val());
    });
```

Check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AgilePlayers/xsvxajur/3/)

Comment: I'm glad it meets your expectations:)

Answer (score 0):

Listen the slider change event,

```
$("#sliderId").on("input change mousemove",function(){
$("input").text($(this).val());
});

$("input").on("change",function(){
//do what you need
});
```

Comment: i need to trigger on the value inside the input when its changed, if posible.

Comment: You want to trigger a event if the slider value changed right?.. `change` will trigger while you after you set the value in the slider and `input` will trigger while you dragging the slider thumb. What you need now other than this

Comment: it updates when i drop, but not while dragging, i need to show updated values while dragging the slider as well.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544890/onchange-event-on-input-type-range-is-not-triggering-in-firefox-while-dragging it may help you