# Google Web Designer dynamically adjust opacity in source code

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-web-designer

Right now I currently have a slider and two images on my Google ad

```
input class="gwd-input-13xh" type="range" min="0" max="50" value="25" id="slider" oninput="getInput(this.value, this.max)">

.img_1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  height: 130px;
  left: 62px;
  top: 1px;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  opacity: .8;
 }

.img_2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  height: 130px;
  left: 62px;
  top: 1px;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  opacity: .8;
 }
```

This slider, if moved right of slider value(higher 25) should remove blur and set opacity to 1. If moved left of slider value(lower 25) then vice versa occurs. Here is the current code I have to do this:

```
function getInput(value, max) {
  var img_1 = document.getElementById("img_1");
  var img_2 = document.getElementById("img_2");
  var sliderPercentage = (value / max).toFixed(2);
  img_1.style.opacity = 1 - sliderPercentage
  setBlur(img_1, (10 * sliderPercentage).toFixed(2));
  img_2.style.opacity = sliderPercentage;
  setBlur(img_2, 10 - (10 * sliderPercentage).toFixed(2));
 }

function setBlur(ele, value) {
  if (ele.style.hasOwnProperty('filter')) {
    ele.setAttribute("style", "-webkit-filter:blur(" + value + "px)")
  }
}
```

This code works flawlessly. However, for whatever reason, the `opacity` will not change. IDK if it is because the `opacity` is set in stone when working within `GWD`. If you `console.log(img_1.style.opacity = 1 - sliderPercentage)` you will see the math on the code works.. it just isn't adjusting the opacity.

Any suggestions and ideas would greatly be appreciated. It also should be noted, when I do NOT run the `setBlur` function then the `setOpacity` function works. It just does not work when I am running `setBlur`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not familiar with GWD either, but I assume the problem is you are re-assigning the whole `style` attribute, so later alteration overrides the former. Replacing `ele.setAttribute("style", "...")` with

```
ele.style["-webkit-filter"] = "blur(" + value + "px)";
```

should fix your issue.

Comment: My hell... after two hours this was the solution. You are the ibuprofen to my headache. God bless.

Comment: Pleasure to help. And thanks Jeremy for corrections.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with GWD but I tried it (with some minor changes):

```
 $("#slider").change(function(){
    var img_1 = document.getElementById("img_1");
  var img_2 = document.getElementById("img_2");
  var sliderPercentage = ($(this).val() / $(this).attr('max')).toFixed(2);
  img_1.style.opacity = 1 - sliderPercentage

setBlur(img_1, (10 * sliderPercentage).toFixed(2));
  img_2.style.opacity = sliderPercentage;
  setBlur(img_2, 10 - (10 * sliderPercentage).toFixed(2));

});

function setBlur(ele, value) {
  if (ele.style.hasOwnProperty('filter')) {
    ele.setAttribute("style", "-webkit-filter:blur(" + value + "px)")
  }
}
```

and I think it behaves as expected.

Please check full solution at:

https://jsfiddle.net/1eumfwoh/

Comment: So I am able to do this when only attempting to do one at a time. If it is that I attempt to adjust both of the css properties at the same time, it does not work. I think this might be a GWD things.