# Change event on input of type range is not working in Angular2 IE 11

Tags: javascript, angular

I can able to get the expected result in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE 11. Even ngModel is also not updating when I change the range.

With the below code I can able to get the alert in the IE but the method assigned to (change) is not working.

Any suggestions please!

```
<input type="range" 
       min = "{{_minimumRangeOfSlider}}" 
       max="{{_maximumRangeOfSlider}}" 
       value="{{_currentRange}}"
       (change) = "plainValueChanged($event)"
       onchange="alert()"
       [(ngModel)] = "_currentRange"
       class="reports-range-slider">
```

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544890/onchange-event-on-input-type-range-is-not-triggering-in-firefox-while-dragging

Comment: I think no, why ngModel is also not updating when I change the range in IE ?

Comment: Are you use a recent Angular2 version (final)?

Comment: Same thing is happening to me.  Bug with IE11.

Answer (score 3):

I got this solved by adding a change event to the range input like so:

```
<input type="range" [(ngModel)]="_currentRange" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
```

You have to make a onChange function in your component to assign what is passed to your value variable.

```
onChange(value:number):void {
    this._currentRange = value;
  }
```

Comment: function call did not get triggered this way in angular 6 at least on my end