# Why event not fired when slider button changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers, bing-maps

I try to bind events to slider button.

Here is my slider button html:

```
 <input id="swipe" type="range" style="width: 100%">
```

And here is Javascript function where I try to bind events:

```
   function createMap() {

    var swipe = document.getElementById('swipe');

    var bing = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.BingMaps({
            key: 'My Bing Map sKey',
            imagerySet: 'Aerial'
        })
    });

    bing.on('precompose', function (event) {

        var ctx = event.context;
        var width = ctx.canvas.width * (swipe.value / 100);

        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(width, 0, ctx.canvas.width - width, ctx.canvas.height);
        ctx.clip();
    });

    bing.on('postcompose', function (event) {
        var ctx = event.context;
        ctx.restore();
    });

    swipe.addEventListener('input', function () {
        map.render();
    }, false);

}
```

As you can see above I have `swipe.addEventListener` that have to be triggered whenever I move the slider.

But `swipe.addEventListener` does not fire when I move the slider, it seems that event not added.

Any idea why event not added? and how to fix it?

**UPDATE**

I get this warning whenever I move slider:

```
The specified value "NaN" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?
```

Comment: I seem to remember it's a bit flaky and behaves differently cross browser - you might have to bind to both `input` and `change` (and then do some handling for any browser that supports both)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onchange event on input type=range is not triggering in firefox while dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544890/onchange-event-on-input-type-range-is-not-triggering-in-firefox-while-dragging)

Comment: Add a `console.log()` inside your event to check if it's firing. Also, "NaN" means "Not a Number" which means that probably some of your variables are "NaN" to begin with. I would use `console.log` to check the value of every variable and see where is the problem.