# get live values of input range in Angular

Tags: angular, input

I am using this code to get the value of a slider:

```
<input type="range" min="30" max="300" value="30" (change)="valueChanged($event)"></div>
```

Unfortunately, the `valueChanged` method is triggered on mouse up. How can I be notified of changes continuously as the thumb is dragged?

`(onmousemove)` does not work.

Comment: please try: oninput check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544890/onchange-event-on-input-type-range-is-not-triggering-in-firefox-while-dragging)

Comment: thanls for stopping by. (oninput)="someFunc($event)" does nothing in angular

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try like this :

```
<input type="range" min="30" max="300" value="30" (input)="valueChanged($event.target.value)">

valueChanged(e) {
    console.log('e', e);
}
```

Comment: Actually replacing `(change)` with `(input)` will do the needed. One can bind the input with a property and use the updated value in the angular code.

`<input type="range" min="0" max="100" [(ngModel)]="strokeWidth" (input)="setStrokeWidth()">{{strokeWidth}}`

Answer (score 4):

Here it is you need to use `(input)` :

```
<input type="range" min="30" max="300" value="30" (input)="valueChanged($event)">

valueChanged(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value);
}
```

---

Here is the link to working example , please have a look :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-range-dynamic-value-change

Answer (score 3):

You can use ngModel to get this or you have to use formcontroller.
In the below sample i have done this with ngmodel ;

```
<input type="range" [ngModel]="mymodel" (ngModelChange)="valueChanged($event)" min="30" max="300" value="30">
```

If you want to use form controller then please use .

```
this.FORMCONTROLLER.valueChanges.subscribe(formValue => {
        this.valueChanged($event)
    });
```