# Making a slider (range) update on slide HTML JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I've got an html range element which updates a number on the page on the realise of the slider marker. I'm wondering if there is a way to make it update this number while it's being moved rather than when realised. This is the code I have:

```js
updateSlider();

function updateSlider() {
  document.getElementById('P1H_value').innerHTML = document.getElementById("P1H").value;
  document.getElementById('P1S_value').innerHTML = document.getElementById("P1S").value;
}
```

```html
<h1>Player 1</h1>
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <h2 align="center">Health:</h2>
  <h3 align="center" id="P1H_value">100</h3>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" class="slider" id="P1H" onChange="updateSlider();">
  <h2 align="center">Shield:</h2>
  <h3 align="center" id="P1S_value">0</h3>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="P1S" onChange="updateSlider();">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `input` event does this on some browsers. ([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19067260/546730) states that IE does not support it.)

```js
updateSlider();

function updateSlider() {
  document.getElementById('P1H_value').innerHTML = document.getElementById("P1H").value;
  document.getElementById('P1S_value').innerHTML = document.getElementById("P1S").value;
}
```

```html
<h1>Player 1</h1>
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <h2 align="center">Health:</h2>
  <h3 align="center" id="P1H_value">100</h3>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" class="slider" id="P1H"
     onchange="updateSlider();" oninput="updateSlider()">
  <h2 align="center">Shield:</h2>
  <h3 align="center" id="P1S_value">0</h3>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="P1S"
     onchange="updateSlider();" oninput="updateSlider()">
</div>
```

Comment: I would go with `onKeyPress`

Comment: @Si8: What, why? Does that capture the mouse? Because it does not seem to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use      **`oninput`**      instead **`onchange`**