# JavaScript Function Exists But It Is Not Being Called

Tags: javascript

I have various functions in this script I am doing, but one of them is not being called despite the two functions knowing about each-other (not a scope issue) and the event listener firing.

I have an [`input` range element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range) with two event listeners, as per this:

[onchange event on input type=range is not triggering in firefox while dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544890/onchange-event-on-input-type-range-is-not-triggering-in-firefox-while-dragging)

My code is like this:

```
function initZoom() {
  var self = this,
  wrap = self.elements.zoomerWrap = document.createElement('div'),
  zoomer = self.elements.zoomer = document.createElement('input');
  self.elements.viewBox.insertAdjacentElement('afterend',wrap);
  wrap.appendChild(zoomer);
  function change() {
    console.log("Fire Before On Zoom!");
    onZoom.call(self, {
      value: parseFloat(zoomer.value),
      origin: new TransformOrigin(self.elements.img),
      viewportRect: self.elements.enclosedCrop.getBoundingClientRect(),
      transform: Transform.parse(self.elements.img)
    });
  }

  self.elements.zoomer.addEventListener('input', change); // this is being fired twice on keypress
  self.elements.zoomer.addEventListener('change', change);

}
```

As you can see I have the two elements (`wrap` and `zoomer`) added to the DOM. This is working, and I also have the two event listeners, which are also working. That is, when I manipulate the range input, I get `Fire Before On Zoom!` printed to the console.

However, my `onZoom` call never seems to fire. I have it here:

```
function onZoom(ui) {
        console.log("Fire Before Apply CSS!");
 }
```

That `console.log()` never prints to the console, and further code in that function never executes. If I put the first `console.log()` behind the `onZoom.call()` it never prints either. If I add `, onZoom` to `console.log("Fire Before On Zoom!")` it prints the function body of `onZoom` so it knows it exists...

So what is wrong with my `onZoom.call()`?

Comment: Can you reproduce this on a fiddle/snippet? Or at least add the whole code?

Comment: @lenilsondc Thanks, as I was doing it, it became clear the reason it was failing was because an argument was undefined. Wondering why that didn't print in my native console...