# input range onChangeComplate event

Tags: html, reactjs, input

I try to implement input range in my react app. But can`t find way how to trigger function when drag is over. Implementation must work on Chrome.

```
      <input
        className="slider"
        onChange={this.handleMinProbabilitySlideChange}
        onMouseUp={this.handleDragEnd} // not working
        onBlur={this.handleDragEnd}    // not working
        value={minProbability}
        type="range"
        min="0"
        max="100"
        step="1"
      />
```

Comment: Why do you need a separate handler for 'drag over' event? `onChange` should be enough to handle changes.

Comment: because by value I create request to server, and I don`t want to do it every time when value is change, just when drag is end

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544890/onchange-event-on-input-type-range-is-not-triggering-in-firefox-while-dragging