# How to change text size with slider?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to write some code to change the size of text dynamically with a slider but it's not working.

```js
$('input').on('change', function() {
  var v = $(this).val();
  $('.userText p').css('font-size', v + 'em')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="range" min="1.2" max="2.6" step=".2" id="slider" />
<div class="userText">
  <p>Some text that should dynamically change size</p>
</div>
```

Can anyone offer any advice here please?

Comment: this is working fine here...

Comment: @RohitVerma I believe they want it to change as the slider moves not once you release it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **onchange** event will fire as soon as you release the mouse button. What you want here is the **oninput** event which will fire as soon as you move the slider.

```js
$('input').on('input', function() {
  var v = $(this).val();
  $('p').css('font-size', v + 'em')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="1.2" max="2.6" step=".2" id="slider" />

<p>Some text that should dynamically change size</p>
```

Answer (score 5):

Just add [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) as an event as well because [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) only fires when the mouse is released. I also added smaller steps and a start value of min for better usability.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', e => document.querySelector('p').style.fontSize = e.target.value + 'em');
```

```html
<input type="range" value="1.2" min="1.2" max="2.6" step=".0002" id="slider" />
<p>Some text that should dynamically change size.</p>
```

For more information on differences across different browsers see [onchange event on input type=range is not triggering in Firefox while dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544890/onchange-event-on-input-type-range-is-not-triggering-in-firefox-while-dragging).

jQuery:

```js
$('input').on('input', e => $('p').css('font-size', $(e.target).val() + 'em'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="range" value="1.2" min="1.2" max="2.6" step=".0002" id="slider" />
<p>Some text that should dynamically change size.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your demo works just fine. However the new value get's applied once you release the slider. 
If you want to update the value instantly, use the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event instead of the [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event:

```js
$('input').on('input', function() {
    var v = $(this).val();
    $('p').css('font-size', v + 'em')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="1.2" max="2.6" step=".2" id="slider" />

<p>Some text that should dynamically change size</p>
```

---

The difference is, `input` occurs, when the value is changed through the user interface. 
`change` on the other hand is fired, when the state of the element has changed.