# get value of slider in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was trying to get the value of a slider in typescript as following:

My html:

```
<input id="width" type="range" value="250" min="50" max="500" (change)="getSliderValue()" />
```

my typescript code in my component.ts:

```
getSliderValue() {
var slider = document.querySelector("#width");
slider.addEventListener('change', () => {
      var data = slider.value
});
}
```

however with this, i get following error on slider.value:

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Element'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There are so many wrong things that I don't know where to start. I'd advise you to take an Angular tutorial, first thing

Comment: That sounds great haha... isn't there a simple short way for this problem? I only need typescript for this one thing and this would pretty much solve everything @CristianTraìna

Comment: Your application is an Angular application (even if you didn't mention it), so you don't need TypeScript for **this**, you need TypeScript for **everything**. The `(change)` keyword in the template is an event bind, so you don't need `addEventListener` since it will do the same thing. You're literally attaching a new event listener for every slide

Comment: yes that i know, the rest is in typescript too that's why i am looking for a typescript instead of JavaScript solution if there is any... I meant that getting the slider value would pretty much solve all of my problems @CristianTraìna

Comment: You don't need to query the dom with `querySelector` this is a bad practice in Angular. You have several ways to get a reference to the element, for example you can pass an `$event` parameter. And, in the end, don't use `var`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I explained pretty much everything in the comments, here is the code:

Html:

```
<input id="width" type="range" value="250" min="50" max="500" (change)="getSliderValue($event)" (oninput)="getSliderValue($event)"  />
```

component.ts:

```
getSliderValue(event) {
   console.log(event.target.value);
}
```

You can read [this article](https://www.impressivewebs.com/onchange-vs-oninput-for-range-sliders/) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544890/onchange-event-on-input-type-range-is-not-triggering-in-firefox-while-dragging) for a better understanding of the `onchange` and `oninput` events.

Comment: check this solution with FF(firefox) This is not working for all the browsers. please check again with all the browsers.

Comment: @Damodhar I don't see anything wrong with Firefox, do you? Feel free to update my answer in case

Comment: Also possible to get the number as number directly using the `valueAsNumber` property instead of plain `value`

Answer (score 0):

I'm follow Cristian and add ngModel binding to label show data

```
<label for="state">My range: <b> {{myValue}}%</b></label>
      <input  name="state" type="range" [(ngModel)]="myValue" (change)="getSliderValue($event)" (oninput)="getSliderValue($event)" id="formControlRange" value="0" min="0"  max="100"   />
```

and component.ts

```
myValue: any=0     
getSliderValue(event:any=0) {
    this.myValue = event.target.value
    console.log(this.myValue );
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to add oninput event as well for listing the slider value change event.

HTML

```
<input id="width" type="range" value="250" min="50" max="500" (change)="getSliderValue(this.value)"  oninput="getSliderValue(this.value)"  />
```

JS

```
<script>
function getSliderValue(value) {
      console.log(value);
}
</script>
```