# How can user trigger links (Slide the ball and mouse up to open that range link) without clicking the button 'Take me to my ideal object!'?

Tags: javascript, html

How can user trigger links without clicking the button 'Take me to my ideal object!' or how can user open a link on slider value change or on mouseup ?
Basically user Slide the ball and mouse up to open that range link.

```js
// Setting custom points to slider
var values = [0, 1000,2000,4000,10000];

var input = document.getElementById('tierslider'),
    output = document.getElementById('tierslider2');
    
input.oninput = function(){
    output.innerHTML = values[this.value];
};

input.oninput();

// Redirect 
function redirectToLinks(elem){
  window.location.href = elem.dataset.baselink + values[input.value];
}
```

```html
<div id='slidecontainer'>
      <form>
          <span>500</span>
          <input type='range' min='0' max='4' value="0" step="1" id='tierslider'>
          <span>10000</span>
          <span id='tierslider2'></span>
      </form>
</div>

<a href='#' data-baselink='http://www.example.com/page?param=' id='DisplaySliderResult' onclick="redirectToLinks(this)">Take me to my ideal object!</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Range sliders are [kind of weird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544890/onchange-event-on-input-type-range-is-not-triggering-in-firefox-while-dragging), but you're on the right track - why not change your 'oninput' function and use [`addEventListener`] to listen to a `change` event (instead of an `input` event)?

In the same way you've updated the value of the `tierslider2` span, you can call you redirect function when this event fires. Event handlers are just that - you get to run your own custom event handling code in them.

```js
// Setting custom points to slider
var values = [0, 1000,2000,4000,10000];

var input = document.getElementById('tierslider'),
    output = document.getElementById('tierslider2'),
    myLink = document.getElementById('DisplaySliderResult');
    


// Redirect 
function redirectToLinks(elem){
  window.location.href = elem.dataset.baselink + values[input.value];
}

input.addEventListener('change', function() {
    // you've already 'handled' this event - now just do what you want! in your case, redirect the user to some other place without them clicking the link
    output.innerHTML = values[this.value];
    redirectToLinks(myLink);
});
```

```html
<div id='slidecontainer'>
      <form>
          <span>500</span>
          <input type='range' min='0' max='4' value="0" step="1" id='tierslider'>
          <span>10000</span>
          <span id='tierslider2'></span>
      </form>
</div>

<a href='#' data-baselink='http://www.example.com/page?param=' id='DisplaySliderResult' onclick="redirectToLinks(this)">Click to take me to my ideal object!</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Brendan Bond sir, It works for me. I'm using this to trigger servo position in esp32 without async server in AP mode. But I have still an issue with this is, when esp32 generates new example page by sliding,but on new example page slider value label (tierslider2) became default that is 0.

Comment: I am developing this code for my application to run a servo in ESP32 Access point mode without asynchronous web server and without ajax query. Ref-https://youtu.be/_WqfNyE_pt8.    Code link-https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-servo-motor-web-server-arduino-ide/

Comment: @GSRathore this sounds like a new issue, please open a new question. If my answer helped you answer this particular question, please accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: No sir, it's not new issue. I am handling local pages like http:///192.168.4.1/sliderValueToMoveServo=180 http:///192.168.4.1/sliderValueToMoveServo=90 degree to update current position of servo to next page. Reloading the same page with changed values.