# How can I centrally align an element to its parent without overflowing?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a range/slider to compare a users results to an average. I'm really struggling to get the text under the slider to behave as I want:

[image: Example]

I have managed to get the arrow, percentage, and text to be centered correctly as in the first two images, but when I set the position too high or low, the text overflows into another area of the page. What I want is behaviour like the last two images, where the text stays within its bounds.

I've tried two different ways with the same end result, and now I'm stuck:

```
<div style="`margin-left:${areaScore}%;margin-right:${100 - areaScore}%;text-align:center`">
    <div style="transform: translateX(-50%)" >^</div>
    <div style="transform: translateX(-50%); width: 50px">
        {{ areaScore }}%
    </div>
    <div style="transform: translateX(-50%); width: 150px">
          The average in your area
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div style="position: relative; text-align: center">
    <div :style="`position:absolute;left:${areaScore}%`">^</div>
    <div :style="`position:absolute;left:${areaScore}%;top:10px`">
        {{ areaScore }}%
    </div>
    <div :style="`position:absolute;left:${areaScore}%;top:24px`">
        The average in your area
    </div>
</div>
```

I should probably mention that I'm using Vue, hence the moustaches, colon before style, and parameterisation of areaScore, but I don't think it's particularly relevant to my problem.

I'm sure this problem is solvable, but I've wasted so much time trying to find a solution, and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires some calculations in JavaScript. I don't know vue so I will give my answer using pure JS. I've put together an example for moving the texts. Let's see the HTML first:

```html
<div class="container">
  <input class="slider" type="range" min="0" max="100">
  <div>
    <span class="percent">50%</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="text">Some long text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I put the text and the percent (like your score) in `span` elements inside of `div` elements. The reason is that the a `div` by default stretches over the complete width (because of `display: block`). Inside needs to be an element whose width we can read and whose position we can manipulate.

Now `span` can't be positioned because it is displayed `inline`. So, I use `display: inline-block` on it:

```css
.percent, .text {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

The last piece is the calculation in JavaScript:

```js
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
const percent = document.querySelector('.percent');
const text = document.querySelector('.text');

slider.value = 50;
setPercent(50);
positionElement(text, 50);

slider.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
  setPercent(event.target.value);
  positionElement(text, event.target.value);
});

function setPercent(value) {
  percent.textContent = value + '%';
  positionElement(percent, value);
}
  
function positionElement(element, value) {
  const width = element.offsetWidth;
  const xPosition = Math.min(Math.max(value - (width / 2), 0), 100 - width);
  element.style.transform = `translateX(${xPosition}px)`;
}
```

The keys are using `translateX` to move the `span` elements like you already did. Using `Math.min` and `Math.max`, we can set boundaries to this movement, depending on the width of the elements. Important: first set the new text and then get the width and change the `translateX`. The 100 is based on a width of 100px of the sliding area.

If we want to update the position while dragging, it is necessary to update on `input` events as found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/19067260/4874075.

I've put the example on codepen: https://codepen.io/andreas-tennert/pen/YzeMoee

Comment: Thank you so much! I was getting lost in CSS and didn't even think to try some javascript! :)