# range Input slider on mobile

Tags: javascript, ios, html, reactjs, mobile-safari

I'm using the default html5 input range object for a custom audio player.
Everything works fine, all the events get fired when I need them and stuff, except I have on annoying issue on my mobile Safari with iOS 11.4:

When I tap on the seekbar/slider, the 'thumb' doesn't jump to the tapped position. I noticed that is the case with any input slider object that I test on my device.

Changing the thumb position by dragging it with onTouchStart/onTouchEnd works fine however.

Anyone who can help me with this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a solution may be posted in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484540/recreating-the-html5-range-input-for-mobile-safari-webkit?rq=1).

> I have exactly the same problem, only with an iPhone.
>
> This is because Mobile Safari only supports a subset of HTML5. I am
>   using JqTouch which is causing me all manner of issues so do avoid
>   this framework.
>
> Take a look at jquery mobile. Its currently Alpha 3, but has a slider
>   control which works on iOS.
>
> Hope this helps you a little.

And another answer suggests using the [range-touch](https://github.com/dwyl/range-touch) library, but assumes you have JQuery for this.